# How can I resolve gradle dependency issues with "cannot read zip file"?

Tags: gradle

I have a project that compiles using gradle with dependencies in a maven repo.

It has been working for many months, but when setting up a new machine, I am unable to compile, with error accessing a dependency file.

```
[ant:javac] error: error reading /Users/rayj/.gradle/caches/artifacts-4/com.google.guava/guava/c12498cf18507aa6433a94eb7d3e77d5/jars/guava-11.0.2.jar; cannot read zip file
I was able to reproduce on another machine by removing my gradle cache ("~/.gradle/caches/artifacts-4/").
```

I was able to determine that the "corrupted" jar file(s) had a behavior different than "non-corrupted" jar files. 
For "non-corrupted" jar files, I can rename to ".zip" and extract the zip to see the contents of the file (as expected). 
For "corrupted" jar files, if I rename to ".zip" and extract the zip, the output is another jar file (unexpected). If I rename/extract again, then it properly extracts as the contents of the file (expected).

I can manually workaround this issue by:

```
for each corrupt jar file { 
  rename to .jar to .zip and extract to create a new jar //this turns a corrupt jar into a non-corrupt jar)
}
```

This suggests that the problem is solely related to a jar file being "corrupt".

Although this works, it is a painful resolution to an automated build =)

I am looking for some guidance as to what may have caused this and how to troubleshoot the root issue.

Comment: Sounds strange. Do you get the same problem with Gradle 1.0? (You seem to be using a fairly old version of Gradle.)

Comment: thx, that seems like such an obvious solution!  If you put that as a "solution" I'll mark as complete.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @peter-niederwieser above, this was resolved by upgrading Gradle!  Easy enough.